# Count from 2 fields

Tags: php, mysql, count, field

As MySQL/PHP Noob I am struggeling to solve the following:

Table called "cars"

Fields called "modell" and "engine"

```
|Modell      |engine  
===================== 
|Volvo       |2,0  
|Volvo       |2,6  
|Volvo       |2,0  
|Saab        |1,8  
|Saab        |2,1  
|Saab        |1,8  
|Saab        |1,8  
|Chevrolet   |4,2
```

Would like to write a question and get as answer:

Here are:

```
2 volvo with 2,0 engine  
1 volvo with 2,6 engine  
3 saab with 1,8 engine  
1 saab with 2,1 engine  
1 Chevrolet with 4,2 engine
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT count(*) AS count,
       Modell,
       engine 
FROM cars 
GROUP BY Modell,engine
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select modell, engine, count(*) as cnt
from cars
group by modell, engine
```

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT COUNT(*),Modell,ENGINE FROM cars GROUP BY modell,ENGINE